# Install Robo 3T on Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Not Studio 3T)

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, studio3t

I need to install robo 3T on ubuntu 22.04.1. But it has latest release called Studio 3T. When i was installed robo 3T it automatically converted to studio 3T. Can anyone guide me to install old version.(Robo 3T).

I also use command line commands and also use binaries.

Comment: [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) is deprecated. Why do you need to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i installed Robo 3T using snap packages.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install robo3t-snap
robo3t-snap
```

Comment: There is a problem while running "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl"
in ""."

Comment: Just run the command `DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 robo3t-snap` and it will open the Robo3T @SzymonRoziewski

Answer (score 2):

- you should start with this command also when your robo3t is installed but not start on Ubuntu linux

  DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 robo3t-snap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).